# Getting the difference (in values) between two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison, difference

Let's say you are given 2 dictionaries, `A` and `B` with keys that can be the same but values (integers) that will be different. How can you compare the 2 dictionaries so that if the key matches you get the difference (eg if `x` is the value from key `"A"` and `y` is the value from key `"B"` then result should be `x-y`) between the 2 dictionaries as a result (preferably as a new dictionary).

Ideally you'd also be able to compare the gain in percent (how much the values changed percentage-wise between the 2 dictionaries which are snapshots of numbers at a specific time).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code and tell us where you got stuck. You should also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

Given two dictionaries, `A` and `B` which may/may not have the same keys, you can do this:

```
A = {'a':5, 't':4, 'd':2}
B = {'s':11, 'a':4, 'd': 0}

C = {x: A[x] - B[x] for x in A if x in B}
```

Which only subtracts the keys that are the same in **both** dictionaries.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `dict` comprehension to loop through the keys, then subtract the corresponding values from each original `dict`.

```
>>> a = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 12}
>>> b = {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 19}
>>> {k: b[k] - a[k] for k in a}
{'a': -4, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
```

This assumes both `dict` have the exact same keys. Otherwise you'd have to think about what behavior you expect if there are keys in one `dict` but not the other (maybe some default value?)

Otherwise if you want to evaluate only shared keys, you can use the set intersection of the keys

```
>>> {k: b[k] - a[k] for k in a.keys() & b.keys()}
{'a': -4, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def difference_dict(Dict_A, Dict_B):
    output_dict = {}
    for key in Dict_A.keys():
        if key in Dict_B.keys():
            output_dict[key] = abs(Dict_A[key] - Dict_B[key])
    return output_dict

>>> Dict_A = {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c':7}
>>> Dict_B = {'a': 3, 'c': 23, 'd': 2}
>>> Diff = difference_dict(Dict_A, Dict_B)
>>> Diff
{'a': 1, 'c': 16}
```

If you wanted to fit that all onto one line, it would be...

```
def difference_dict(Dict_A, Dict_B):
    output_dict = {key: abs(Dict_A[key] - Dict_B[key]) for key in Dict_A.keys() if key in Dict_B.keys()}
    return output_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the difference of similar keys into a new dictionary, you could do something like the following:

```
new_dict={}
for key in A:
    if key in B:
        new_dict[key] = A[key] - B[key]
```

...which we can fit into one line

```
new_dict = { key : A[key] - B[key] for key in A if key in B }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a python package for this case:

https://dictdiffer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from dictdiffer import diff
print(list(diff(a, b)))
```

would do the trick.